# How to have a "focal chart" layout similar to flexdashboard in shinydashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I'm making the transition from flexdashboard to shinydashboard and this is probably simpler than I am making it out to be.

I have this layout that I can easily make in flexdashboard.

````
---
title: "Focal Chart (Left)"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---
    
Column {data-width=600}
-------------------------------------
    
### Chart 1
    
```{r}
```
   
Column {data-width=400}
-------------------------------------
   
### Chart 2

```{r}
```   
 
### Chart 3
    
```{r}
```
````

It gives me this output
[image]

I am trying to make this same layout in shiny but for some reason I can't?

Here is what I have tried.

````
```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot1")), box(plotOutput("plot2"))
    ),
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot3"))
    )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot(
    ggplot(mtcars,aes(hp,mpg)) + 
    geom_point()
  )
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot(
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, cyl)) + 
      geom_point()
  )
  
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot(
    mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% count() %>% 
      ggplot(aes(cyl,n)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

```
````

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      column(6,box(width=12,plotOutput("plot1", height=740))),
      column(6,
        box(width=12, plotOutput("plot2", height=350)),
        box(width=12, plotOutput("plot3", height=350))
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for that, do you know what the 6 means and it is possible to minimize the space between the 2 columns?

Comment: I have split the 12 columns to 6 each.  You can split whichever way you want.  By default, box() takes 50% of the available space; use 12 to make it 100% of (original 6 from column(6,...)) the available space.  You can play with some CSS code, to adjust spacing.